# wrapping inside preview pane of TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I'd like text in the *inline* preview pane to wrap according to its width. Currently the preview pane assumes the width of the document class and I have to use the horizontal scrollbar to see all of the preview.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the zoom on preview window using the buttons on the top right.

In the image below it is adjusted to the width.

[image]

Comment: I meant inline preview tab.

Comment: @m33lky, in this case, try to ask here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/